# How to realize DropDownListFor in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to show all names of "Category" in the dropdownlist in Create View by HtmlHelper.

The Model of "Category" is:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller is:

```
public ActionResult Create()//
{
    ViewBag.Categorys = new SelectList(categoryRepo.SelectAll(), "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

The View is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Categorys, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Is it working or not? if not what is the error?

Answer (score -2):

You may try this,

```
@Html.DropDownList("Categorys", null, "Select Category", new {@class="form-control"})
```